# Symfony doesn't remove cache by tags

Tags: symfony, caching

Symfony version: 3.4.9

Reproducing:

```
$cache = new TagAwareAdapter($this->get('cache.app'));
$pagination = $cache->getItem(PostTypeDictionary::CACHE_MEDIA_PREFIX . $postType . $request->get('page', 1));

if (!$pagination->isHit()) {
    $data = getSomeData();

    $pagination->tag(
        [
            PostTypeDictionary::CACHE_MEDIA_PREFIX,
            PostTypeDictionary::CACHE_MEDIA_PREFIX . $postType,
        ]
    );
    $pagination->set($data);
    $cache->save($pagination);
} else {
    $data = $pagination->get();
}
```

In redis i see two keys:
1) "zG3lSHyaSM:\x00tags\x00cache.media.01"
2) "zG3lSHyaSM:cache.media.01"

First contains: `"a:2:{s:12:\"cache.media.\";i:0;s:13:\"cache.media.0\";i:0;}"`

Second contains data

Then i call cache clearing by tags:

```
(new TagAwareAdapter($this->get('cache.app')))->invalidateTags([PostTypeDictionary::CACHE_MEDIA_PREFIX]);
```

Redis store one more key "zG3lSHyaSM:cache.media.\x00tags\x00", which contains: `"i:1;"`

And that's all, old cache available.
Another cache adapters have the same problem.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found that Symfony's cache component has a bug in a most recent version (3.4.9). I think it's related to https://github.com/symfony/cache/commit/51a9eef3091b2c06f63d8b1b98de9d101b5e0e77 . Simply downgrading to 3.4.8 solved this issue for me.